# Adding another condition to the existing min max in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find out which Couriers are eligible for bonus pay and here's my code:

```
df['Bonus'] = df['Delivered'].mul(0.14).where(df['Average Parcels'].between(10, 18, "left"),0)
```

So right now it has the condition that to be eligible, you must reach an average of a minimum of 10 parcels delivered and a max of 18.

I want to add another line to cap the value at 18. So any values returned in `Average Parcels` that is over 18, I want the code to replace that value with the cap. So if a courier managed to deliver 25 on average, I'd like it to be replaced with 18 so they are included in the bonus pay.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`.clip()` seemed to have worked for me

I applied that to the `Average Parcels` column with

`df['Average Parcels'] = (df['Delivered']/df['Hours']).clip(upper=18)`